# Non-italic text command

Tags: macros, italic

I would like a command, \foo, that always gives the word "foo" as a non-italic text in math mode.

If I write

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\text{foo}}
```

then in an italic environment (like theorem statement), it will give an italic "foo". On the other hand, if I write

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\emph{foo}}
```

then in a non-italic environment, it will give an italic "foo".

How can this be done?

Comment: You can use `\textup`.

Comment: `\text` should never be used to force upright for this very reason. Never understood why so many people think `\text` is to be used for that. As campa says use `\textup` or event `\textnormal`. It also depends on that `foo` is here. If this is a math construction, then it probably should not be in the text font in the first place and `\mathrm` could be a more correct macro to use.

Comment: Can you please add a few examples where you use `\text` in math mode? Chances are that there are better tools than `\textup` for solving the issue.